# Unable to change the date or time?

Tags: windows-7, asus-laptop, system-date

I recently took apart my Asus U46E-BAL7 laptop and I had to disconnect the CMOS battery to get to the fan.

I put it back together successfully, but when Windows 7 boots up the date and time are wrong, as expected. Also a few programs, like Firefox, will fail to launch when I try to open them.

However, when I try to change the time in the date and time settings it doesn't let me. A message about daylight savings starts flashing in the window and I can't close the window, and task-manager won't start. I can't really do anything at all other that move the cursor around. The same thing happens when I try to do it in Safe Mode.

I've already tried to Google it, but no one seems to be having a similar issue.

Any ideas/suggestions on what's going on or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you set the system time in BIOS? If you disconnected the CMOS battery, the time will need to be reset. Then try setting the time in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the system time in the BIOS. It's possible that It's unable to save the time due to a problem with the system clock.

When you first turn on your computer there should be a message saying something like "press F2 for setup" Press it quickly.

Every bios is a bit different, but if you navigate you should see a time setting. Set it to the correct time and see what happens.

If it *still* does not set correctly you could have a dead or incorrectly inserted battery.